# jquery to get html data and store into array

Tags: php, jquery

```js
var a = $('.opti').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('value');
}).toArray();

var b = $('.opti').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('vid');
}).toArray();


console.log(a, b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="opti" value="337" vid="231">
```

**Output**

["337"]
["231"]

Question: Above code is return the data in separate array, but what I want is put them into one array, for example it will be one array to store is 2 value, result will be ["337","231"].

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of `.opti`? Do you want to store them in an array of arrays (a 2D array containing elements with pairs of data), or a 1D array?

Comment: i think 2d array will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return array of both value and vid property using one `map()` method.

```js
var attr = $(".opti").map(function() {
  return [$(this).val(), $(this).attr('vid')]
}).get();

console.log(attr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="opti" value="337" vid="231">
```

To get 2D array for multiple `input` elements you can return `[[$(this).val(), $(this).attr('vid')]]` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2132/) as suggested by `@Terry`

Comment: If OP wants a 2D array (for situations where multiple elements matches the selector), you should return a nested array: `[[$(this).val(), $(this).attr('vid')]]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for multiple instances of "opti" elements

```js
var result = [];
$(".opti").each(function () {
  result.push([$(this).val(), $(this).attr("vid")]);
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="opti" value="337" vid="231">
<input type="hidden" class="opti" value="336" vid="233">
<input type="hidden" class="opti" value="335" vid="232">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .push methon and you can use many arguments, and .apply to pass all the elementos of the second array.

a.push.apply(a, b)